# WooCommerce API Get User Information

Tags: php, api, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

so I've been trying to get the WooCommerce REST API to give me single users and all users information to no avail, I keep getting the error:

```
{
    "code": "woocommerce_rest_cannot_view",
    "message": "Sorry, you cannot list resources.",
    "data": {
        "status": 403
    }
}
```

Using Basic Auth with an https address, the API has both read/write permissions as well.
Using the format of:

```
https://exampledomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers/
```

Comment: This may be stupid, but have you tried dropping the trailing slash and/or making it http instead of https?

Comment: @Jason At this point I'll try anything lmao , did that and still same exact error.

Comment: That sometimes helped me...  Anyway, this obviously an auth issue...  Have you tried regenerating your API keys?  Are you using Postman?  Maybe try another tool, like https://reqbin.com/ or https://hoppscotch.io/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reset admin and it worked like a charm, weird as hell but yep.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that your server doesn't parse the Authorization header correctly.  Try to to send the credentials as query string parameters like this:

```
https://www.example.com/wp-json/wc/v3/customers?consumer_key=123&consumer_secret=abc
```

Comment: ``` {"code":"woocommerce_rest_cannot_view","message":"Sorry, you cannot list resources.","data":{"status":403}} ``` Same error through that as well